# regex syntax in python, the r before the opening quote

Tags: python, regex, syntax

This is a line of regex from a Python thing I'm writing:

```
m = re.match(r"{(.+)}", self.label)
```

As far as i can tell, it's working fine.

Anyways, my question is about the r character before the first double quote.  I've never really questioned it.  But why is it there?  What is its purpose?

Comment: Since this is closed (dubious; the supposed answer is not an answer to this question), I'll post my answer as a comment. The `r` before the opening quote means what follows is a raw string literal. In those raw string literals, a backslash mean just that, a backslash. Many regular expressions are loaded with backslashes (yours isn't). Having to double up those backslashes is a royal pain, hence the raw string literals. It's common practice to always use `r"<string>"` with regular expressions, even if it doesn't do anything (as in your example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `r` before a string literal tells Python not to do any `\` escaping on the string. For instance:

```
>>> print('a\nb')
a
b
>>> print(r'a\nb')
a\nb
>>>
```

The reason `r`-prefixed strings are often used with regular expressions is because regular expressions often use a lot of `\`'s. For instance, to use a simple example, compare the regular expression `'\\d+'` versus `r'\d+'`. They're actually the same string, just represented in different ways. With the `r` syntax, you don't have to escape the `\`'s that are used in the regular expression syntax. Now imagine having a lot of `\`'s in your regular expression; it's much cleaner to use the `r` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

"String literals may optionally be prefixed with a letter 'r' or 'R'; such strings are called raw strings and use different rules for interpreting backslash escape sequences."

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals